# Checking complex types in emacs lisp?

Tags: tree, elisp, typechecking

In emacs lisp, is there some boilerplate-less way to check for type-conditions such as "list of numbers" with clear error messages?

The `cl-check-type` macro is quite useful for verifying the type of an argument, preventing obscure error messages occurring when invalid input produces a type-error somewhere in a subfunction of a subfunction.

However, I cannot find a good way of verifying even moderately complex types in a manner that produces a clear error message, without adding a lot of boilerplate code.

A clear error-message should contain the name of the argument, and state what the argument is expected to fulfill and typically the value of the argument (though that might actually be a bad idea for arguments that are potentially large trees).

#### Example

Assume a function `(mysum NUMLIST)` that expects a list of numbers as argument. If a `wrong-type-argument` is signal'ed, the error signal should ideally contain the variable name of the argument, and explain what was expected.

In this simple example, the condition can be violated in three ways:

- *NUMLIST* may not be a list (cons or nil).
- *NUMLIST* may not be a *proper list*, e.g. `(1 2 . 3)`.
- An entry of *NUMLIST* may not be a number.

Ideally all this would be covered by something like

```
;; Pseudocode, doesn't actually work
(cl-check-type numlist (listof numberp))
```

As far as I can tell, there is no variant of the `cl-check-type` macro that allows saying "a list of items that each fulfill a type predicate", so it cannot be used directly. Usually I'd instead write something like

```
(cl-check-type numlist list)
(dolist (item list)
  (cl-check-type item numberp))
```

but this would produce inferior error messages:

- For *NUMLIST* being `(1 2 . 3)`, both error-message and stack-trace wouldn't easily make clear, that the issue arises because of `numlist`.
- For numlist being `(1 b 3)`, the error-message would refer to the internal variable `item`, instead of indicating what function argument the item came from.

The best I could come up with is

```
(condition-case nil
    (dolist (item numlist)
      (cl-check-type item numberp))
  (wrong-type-argument
    (signal 'wrong-type-argument
      (list '(listof numberp) numlist 'numlist))))
```

with the disadvantage of using a pseudo-predicate `(listof ...)`, that lacks a well-defined meaning.

While it would be possible to define a predicate `mypackage-list-of-numbers-p`, the resulting error

```
(wrong-type-argument mypackage-list-of-numbers-p SOME-VALUE-IN-VIOLATION numlist)
```

wouldn't be nearly as self-explanatory as being able to use a predefined predicate; If `listof` were a valid type predicate, the exact meaning of `(listof numberp)` would be assumed to be known to the programmer seeing the error message, while `mypackage-list-of-numbers-p` might hide any number of surprises (e.g. requiring the number to be an integer), and defining `mypackage-list-of-numbers-p` would still consititute boilerplate code.

#### Recursive types with ‘define-widget’

The problem becomes worse for more complex strutures, especially recursive structures like arbitary-depth trees. At that point the boilerplate can be reduced by defining (and checking against) custom types defined with `define-widget`, which also allows recursion.

For a simple cases like "list of numbers" however, this seems like massive overkill, both in terms lines-of-code and in terms of how much documentation a programmer using the function needs to look up.

Answer (score 2):

As far as the example is concerned, `eieio` defines `list-of`, which you can use with another type as argument in `cl-check-type`. (Bonus points to them for **not** sticking to naming conventions).

```
(cl-typep '(1 2 3) '(list-of number))   ;; => t
(cl-typep '(1 2 . 3) '(list-of number)) ;; => wrong-type argument, 3 is not a list
(cl-typep nil '(list-of number))        ;; => t, as nil is a list
(cl-typep "foo" '(list-of number))      ;; => nil
```

For more complex examples, you may want to look into `cl-deftype`, which lets you define your own types. As an example:

```
(cl-deftype nonempty-list-of (elem-type)
  `(and (list-of ,elem-type)
        (satisfies (lambda (list) (not (null list))))))
(cl-typep '(1 2 3) '(nonempty-list-of number)) ;; => t
(cl-typep nil '(nonempty-list-of number))      ;; => nil
```

It should be noted, that type definitions are even harder to track down than ordinary predicates. They are stored as a property of some symbol, lack any form of documentation and may even be compiled. People who read that assert will usually have to grep your source code for its definition, if the name does not already make sense.

If your data structure is *really* complex, I would suggest using widgets rather than typedefs, since they also help with writing customizations.
The boilerplate for checking is comparatively simple:

```
(widget-apply (widget-convert 'mywidget) :match mydata) ;; => non-nil if mydata is valid for mywidget
```

Of course, you can wrap it in a `cl-assert` or something like that. If your structure has any deeper meaning associated with it, you may also want to look deeper into `eieio`, which can also help you in other ways. Notably, you can define classes with generated type predicates, and said classes have slots, whose types can be checked at instantiation time via `cl-` type macros, thus forming a closed circle.

Comment: In most cases the `cl-deftype` route (which I wasn't aware of) should be quite sufficient. Most cases are simple like `list-of`. But the lack of documentation really *is* an issue, and wasting Emacs Lisp's (subjectively) greatest strength. Also, namespaces...

Comment: With widgets, is it possible to get more meaningful error messages than "not a list of integers", like your `wrong-type argument, 3 is not a list` example? Producing error messages that indicate *where* things went wrong are one of the reasons my boilerplate code gets verbose.

Comment: @kdb You can use widgets in conjunction with `cl-deftype`, but that will  (hopefully) only result in messages like "foo is not a foo-type". "3 is not a list" is actually an error thrown by `car` in `cl-every`, which is used in the definition of `list-of`. It is not the kind of error you'd want, especially if your data structure has lots of 3s at different places.

Comment: @kdb As far as meaningful errors are concerned, I think you might be using widgets (or data structures in general) wrong, if that kind of help is not enough.
For instance, '(1 2 3 "foo") is not a list of integers should be "as good" as "foo" is not an integer. Of course, that depends on where you catch your errors, but you can have it both ways. A good rule of thumb is to assert the type where it's necessary and throw an error there. Then you can `toggle-debug-on-error` to get a trace of how something went wrong, while also knowing the element that caused the error due to the error itself.